# En phpMyAmin la tabla se ve correctamente, pero en mi web no se ven correctamente las ñ

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, utf-8, caracteres

Poseo una tabla que tiene datos con ñ.
Esta es la estructura

[image: Esta es la estructura:]

Estos son lo datos:

[image: Datos]

Por otro lado yo cargo los datos y los muestro con php asi:(código básico de prueba)

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    ?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <?
    include('Conexion.php');
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db);


    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `SubTipoArea` WHERE TipoArea_id='$id'");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
     echo utf8_decode($row['SubTipoArea_name']).'<br>';

     }
    ?>
```

Los datos se ven asi

```
Dise?o
Dise?o de interiores Decoracion
Dise?o Grafico
Dise?o Industrial
Dise?o Multimedia
Dise?o textil e indumentaria
Dise?o Web
Dise?o 3D
```

Hice un bakcup en sql de la base y la codifique nuevamente con el notepad plus, como alguien me recomendó y nada..

NO se que mas hacer...

PD agrego:
La base esta configurada asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en que codificación esta la tabla? también es importante y no se muestra en las capturas. Deberías revisar tabla/base de datos y configuración de mysql. phpMyAdmin te lo puede chivar todo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base)

Comment: Mork, Ahi agregue la configuración de la base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade

```
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES utf8;")
```

justo después del `mysqli_connect()`.

Y juega con el `utf8_decode()` y el `utf8_encode()` que tienes en el `while`. En cada nueva versión del PHP hemos tenido que ir ajustando las codificaciones de caracteres para mantener la compatibilidad.

Comment: Agregue esto y me da este error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function msyqli_query()

Comment: Disculpa, escribí mal el nombre de la función :) Es la misma que usas dos líneas más abajo

Comment: Perdón, no entendí: Como es entonces?

Comment: Gracias David, lo solucione poniendo la isntruccion que me recomendaste y luego en el while puse esto.
echo utf8_decode(utf8_encode($row['SubTipoArea_name'])).'<br>';

Comment: En ese caso, puedes quitar ambos: el encode y el decode :)

Comment: Podes creer, que lo saco y me lo pone mal de nuevo... es raro, no?

Comment: Ya te digo que depende del servidor, de la versión de PHP... La codificación de caracteres siempre da un poco de guerra...